# How to map an http .get observable response to handle object of arrays or array of objects

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, observable

My code is below, it expects the endpoint to be in the form of an array of items like this `[{},{},{}...]`:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "item1"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "item2"
  }
]
```

But some endpoints use a root node identifier/label like `{[{},{},{}...]}`

```
{
 "items": [
  {
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "item1"
  },
  {
    "id": 1, 
    "name": "item2"
  }
 ]
}
```

To handle the latter case, I have added the "startNode" parameter. For example, in the second JSON above, the code expects to pass in "items" as the startNode. I would like to refactor the response observable so that it automatically handles both formats without need to know the startNode:

```
getEndpoint(event: CustomEvent) {
  const mappedValues = mapValuesKeyBy(event.detail, 'name', 'value');
  let endpoint = trim(mappedValues._endpoint) || 'http://localhost:4100/states';
  const labelKey = trim(mappedValues._labelKey);
  const valueKey = trim(mappedValues._valueKey);
  const labelFormat = mappedValues._labelFormat;
  const hiddenColumns = trim(mappedValues._hiddenColumns);
  const startNode = trim(mappedValues._startNode);

  this.appService.get(endpoint, {}).subscribe(result => {
    
    if(typeof(result[0]) === 'undefined' && result[startNode]) {
      result = result[startNode];
    } else {
      endpoint = 'http://localhost:4100/states';
    }
    
    const titleMap: TitleMapItem[] = map(result, value => ({
        name: labelFormat ? this.jsf.parseVariables(labelFormat, value) : value[labelKey],
        value: value[valueKey]
      }));
      
    this.setTitleMap(event, titleMap);

    /** NOTE - remaps the original <mat-select> dynamic list to the Properties <mat-autocomplete> for setting the `defaultValue` */
    const tableConfig: AutoCompleteTableConfig = {
      labelKey,
      valueKey,
      hiddenColumns: hiddenColumns || []
    };
    this.setAutoCompleteList(event, result, tableConfig);
  });
}
```

An example of the first use case endpoint is here:
https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

An example of the second use case endpoint is here: https://dummyjson.com/products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably better to properly type your endpoints, but here's how you can do it:

```
this.appService.get(endpoint, {}).subscribe(result => {
    if (!Array.isArray(result)) {
        result = Object.values(result)[0];
    }
    
    // ...
});
```

This works by first checking if the `result` [is an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) , and by taking the first [object value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) if it's not.

Of course, this assumes that you only have array and single key objects. Like I said, better to properly type your endpoints.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By "properly type" you mean as like endpoint: url[] with an interface for example or are you suggesting something more?